# How to display data on top of others instead of simultaneously with React checkboxes?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, setstate

I am new to React and trying to build a TODO app. What I'm trying to achieve is: 1) after each checkbox's click, I would like to show its associated data on top of what is already displayed rather than simultaneously (i.e checkbox 2 displaying its data instead of replacing another checkbox's data).

I guess it has something to do with the way I'm storing and filtering my items but I'm struggling to find the way out.

Also, and for it to be perfect, 2) I'd like to remove the behaviour that checking/unchecking my checkboxes is performing the same action (i.e when all checkboxes are clicked, unticking one will call again its associated function rather than doing nothing and keep its data displayed on the screen) and 3) allowing the fact that some checkboxes cannot be both ticked at the same time (the Clear and Show all checkboxes for example).

Thanks in advance

**CODE**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Items from "./Items.js"

class Checkbox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    Data: Items,
    storeData: Items,
    }
  }

  myFunction = (category) => {
    const filterData = this.state.Data.filter(elem => elem.category === category);
    this.setState({storeData: filterData});
  }

  myFunctionAll = () => {
    this.setState({storeData: Items});
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.storeData)
    console.log(this.state.Data)
    return(
      <div>
        <label>
          Filter A
          <input type="checkbox" onClick={() => this.myFunction("A")} />
        </label>
        <label>
          Filter B
          <input type="checkbox" onClick={() => this.myFunction("B")} />
        </label>
        <label>
          Filter C
          <input type="checkbox" onClick={() => this.myFunction("C")} />
        </label>
        <label>
          Clear All
          <input type="checkbox" onClick={() => this.myFunction(null)} />
        </label>
        <label>
          Show All
          <input type="checkbox" onClick={() => this.myFunctionAll()} />
        </label>

        <br />
        {this.state.storeData.map(elem => (
          <li key={elem.id}>
            Id: {elem.id} Category: {elem.category}
          </li>))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Checkbox />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

**DATA**

```
const Items = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "First item",
      "category": "A"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Second item",
      "category": "B"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Third item",
      "category": "C"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Fourth item",
      "category": "A"
    },
  ]
  
  export default Items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main issue with your code is trying to filter and save back into state your data. I think it is better to instead keep your data intact, i.e. don't mutate it, and instead store in state what "filters" are active. You can simply filter your state data array in the render function on-the-fly.

Add a `filters` object to your state.

```
state = {
  data: Items,
  filters: {}
};
```

Create a `toggleFilter` function to consume an `onChange` event. This will toggle what filters are active (i.e. checked) in state.

```
toggleFilter = (e) => {
  const { name, checked } = e.target;
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    filters: {
      ...prevState.filters,
      [name]: checked
    }
  }));
};
```

Add a `name` attribute and `onChange` handler to each checkbox input, where `X` is the name of each filter, i.e. "A", "B", or "C".

```
<label>
  Filter X
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    name='X'
    onChange={this.toggleFilter}
    checked={!!this.state.filters.X} // <-- coerce to boolean so value is defined
  />
</label>
```

Finally, filter and map your data. If *some* filters object value is truthy then check which filter is active against the current element's category, otherwise just return true to indicate the value *should not* be filtered from the result array.

```
{this.state.data
  .filter((el) => {
    const { filters } = this.state;
    if (Object.values(filters).some(Boolean)) { // <-- if some filter is active
      if (filters.NONE) return false; // <-- if clear all active then filter out
      return filters.ALL || filters[el.category]; // <-- check if ALL or category active
    }
    return true;
  })
  .map((elem) => (
    <li key={elem.id}>
      Id: {elem.id} Category: {elem.category}
    </li>
  ))}
```

[image: Edit how-to-display-data-on-top-of-others-instead-of-simultaneously-with-react-checkb]

Full Code

```
const filterOptions = [
  {
    filter: "A",
    label: "Filter A"
  },
  {
    filter: "B",
    label: "Filter B"
  },
  {
    filter: "C",
    label: "Filter C"
  },
  {
    filter: "NONE",
    label: "Clear All"
  },
  {
    filter: "ALL",
    label: "Show All"
  }
];

class Checkbox extends Component {
  state = {
    data: Items,
    filters: {}
  };

  toggleFilter = (e) => {
    const { name, checked } = e.target;
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      filters: {
        ...prevState.filters,
        [name]: checked
      }
    }));
  };

  clearFilters = () => this.setState({ filters: {} });

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {filterOptions.map(({ filter, label }) => (
          <label key={filter}>
            {label}
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name={filter}
              onChange={this.toggleFilter}
              checked={!!this.state.filters[filter]}
            />
          </label>
        ))}
        <button type="button" onClick={this.clearFilters}>
          Clear Filters
        </button>

        <br />
        {this.state.data
          .filter((el) => {
            const { filters } = this.state;
            if (Object.values(filters).some(Boolean)) {
              if (filters.NONE) return false;
              return filters.ALL || filters[el.category];
            }
            return true;
          })
          .map((elem) => (
            <li key={elem.id}>
              Id: {elem.id} Category: {elem.category}
            </li>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow! I never expected to receive such a clear and detailed answer. I cannot thank you enough for this, I learned a lot!
If I may, there are 2 more things: 
- now, once I pressed any checkbox I got an error msg "A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type checkbox to be controlled."
- for the "Clear All" checkbox I was talking about, it was because I would like this checkbox to hide/erase everything there currently is on the screen so if I clicked on all markers, this checkbox would empty everything, is it smth I could add to the ClearAll function like a second setState maybe?

Comment: @AlexGlm The controlled/uncontrolled warning is because the `checked` state values are initially `undefined`. This can be fixed by coercing them to boolean when setting the prop, `checked={!!this.state.filters[filter]}`. I updated the answer and sandbox to also use a "Clear All" checkbox and how it can "override" all the other checkbox values in the filter function.

Comment: Thank you so so much, it's perfect you have been very helpful. I wish you a wonderful day ahead!

Comment: Done at the moment (couldn't do before as I did not have 15 points yet on here). Cheers :)

Comment: @AlexGlm To deselect all other options when "Clear All" is active spread the `filters` state as such: `filters: { ...(name === "NONE" ? {} : prevState.filters), [name]: checked }`. To default to displaying nothing when no checkboxes are active simply invert the default return value in the filter function, return false. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-display-data-on-top-of-others-instead-of-simultaneously-with-react-checkb-forked-o8jfm?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: thank you very much again for all this. I'll keep trying to integrate all this good work into my map. Cheers :)